# StreamInsight adapter

Tags: c#, streaminsight

Do the I/O adapters have to run on the same computer as the StreamInsight service? In other words- Is it possible to run the input adapter on an application server while StreamInsight runs on the back end server?

Answer (score 1):

The adapters have to run in the same process as the StreamInsight server. However, it is perfectly fine to use an adapter that can act as client and server of the event data flow. The WCF sample adapter, for instance, has one component that creates an endpoint and runs in the process of the StreamInsight server (calling the enqueue method), and a client component that sends the event data to said endpoint. See also http://streaminsight.codeplex.com/releases/view/46435.